# Paperclip with form_tag without corresponding model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, paperclip

I have a form with pictures to upload, but this form is not built directly on model, I am using `form_tag` instead of `form_for`.

I'd like to upload the images and save them with Paperclip, but how can I make Paperclip understand the params from my form?

`@user.avatar.picture = params[:my_file_field]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correct some of your terminology, Paperclip *has* to be attached to a model, otherwise you'd not be able to save the files you have.

The issue you have is that you're trying to populate a model which is not corresponding to your routing structure (IE you're passing *only* the picture attributes and need a way to parse it with Paperclip).

You'll still have a controller/action & model to populate...

---

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, path: "profile", only: [:index] do 
   patch :avatar, on: :member #-> url.com/profile/:id/avatar
end

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def avatar
       @user = User.find params[:id]
       @user.update avatar_params
   end

   private

   def avatar_params
       params.require(:user).permit(avatar_attributes: [:picture])
   end
end

#app/views/users/show.html.erb
<%= form_for @user, url: user_avatar_path(@user) do %>
   <%= f.fields_for :avatar do |a| %>
      <%= a.file_field :picture %>
   <% end %>
   <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

--

If you wanted to stick to `form_tag`, you'll need to cut out the model-level params:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, path: "profile", only: [:index] do
   patch :avatar, on: :member
end

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def avatar
      @user = User.find params[:id]
      @user.avatar.update avatar_params
   end

   private

   def avatar_params
      params.permit(:picture)
   end
end

#app/views/users/show.html.erb
<%= form_tag users_avatar_path(@user) do %>
   <%= file_field_tag :picture %>
   <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Several pointers:

1. `form_tag` won't show errors
2. Your `file_field` needs to be named the same as your `paperclip` attachment

Comment: Thanks for your response. My attachments are associated with a model and they are working. My question specifically about `file_field_tag`. Would it be possible to save a file using Paperclip if `file_field_tag` has a different name?

Comment: Yes, you'd just set the paperclip object explicitly: `@object = Object.new` `@object.attachment = params[:your_file_field]` `@object.save`

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more descriptive about the issue.what I understand you have issue with form_tag

If you are using a form_tag then you should use the proper form_tag format.

```
form_tag(controller: "people", action: "search", method: "get", class: "nifty_form")
```

for example you have to do like that

```
<%= form_tag :controller => 'images', :action => 'create', :method => "get", :multipart => true do %>
```

Comment: Actually, the `form_tag` is working. My question is, if the `file_field_tag` is not directly associated with the model, how can I force Paperclip to understand it and save the file.